# Asp.Net HttpHandler and jQuery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, zip, httphandler, content-type

These are 2 questions.
The first one:
I have an HttpHandler returning a zip file to download.
I have this line of code:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myzipfile.zip");
```

The question is: should I declare the `ContentType` (application/zip) also ?

The second question is:
I want to call this HttpHandler from a jQuery ajax call.
I send parameters in json format.
How should I declare the `contentType` of the ajax call?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> > The question is: should I declare the ContentType (application/zip) also ?

Yes.

> > I want to call this HttpHandler from a jQuery ajax call

Calling a server side script that returns binary zip stream using AJAX makes little sense as you won't be able to manipulate the response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you suggest for the scenario I described?

Comment: You haven't described any scenario. You just asked two questions to which I gave an answer. If you want an user to be able to download a file create a simple link that points to your ashx handler. No need of AJAX: `<a href="/yourhandler.ashx?param1=value1">Download ZIP</a>`.

Comment: I explain you better what I want to do. HttpHandler returns different status codes in case of errors. I want to manage these ones and then I want to call the httphandler sending params in Post. I think I can't do this with a simple link. What do you suggest for doing this?

Comment: You could use a `<form action="/yourhandler.ashx" method="POST">` in this case.

Comment: I can't I think, I have my form in a masterpage. I'm trying with an ajax call (jQuery), my httphandler works fine but I can't get the file to download, the ajax call seems to throw an error. I should declare a dataType for the ajax call but what about a zip file? I really thank you for your time.